# How can I make a REST XMLHttpRequest call from AFrame while using 8th Wall Web?

Tags: rest, api, xmlhttprequest, aframe, 8thwall-web

I am using 8th Wall SDK and trying to call an API.  When I am attempting to do that from  AFrame.registercomponent onclick method, the request is not getting sent.

I am new to AR.  When I tried adding an alert messages for xhttp, it's empty.

What am I missing?

Is there an alternative to this?

By the way, I tried doing this with with an AR marker using Awe.js and it worked fine.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('play-on-window-click', {
  ...
  ...
  onClick: function(evt) {
    var video = this.el.components.material.material.map.image;

    // I'm sending a request from here - BEGIN
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.status == 200) {
          this.responseText;
        }
      xhttp.open("GET", "https://myapi/rest/abc", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    // END

    video.play();
  }
}
```

I expect the call is made successful to the API.

Comment: did you find an answer to the?

Comment: looking to implement a few get/posts in an aframe 8th wall project too :)

Answer (score 2):

The `xhttp.open` and `xhttp.send` calls are inside the `onreadystatechange` handler so it will not get sent. Something like this should work:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('play-on-window-click', {
  ...
  ...
  onClick: function(evt) {
    var video = this.el.components.material.material.map.image;

    // I'm sending a request from here - BEGIN
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        alert(this.responseText);
      }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://myapi/rest/abc", true);
    xhttp.send();
    // END

    video.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But still I don't see a request getting sent.  However, the `xhttp.open` & `send` call are outside of the `xhttp.onreachstatechagne`.  Also, when I added an `alert` message with `http.onreachstatechagne`, it didn't popup anything.

Comment: Are you sure the onClick function is getting called?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I have put `alert` message which gets displayed on the device.